# Why am I getting directory listing denied when using the default route on iis 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I'm trying to deploy an mvc 2 website and I succeeded somehow, but there is a little problem.

When I browse to `192.168.36.129:83/home.aspx` everything is fine and works, but if I go to
`192.168.36.129:83/`, directory listing denied is shown, which means (I think) no routes matched.

I followed [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Default.aspx to the default documents list served by IIS.

Check this URL for instructions on how to do it: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320051

Comment: I added default.aspx but it is not working. I tried home.aspx but it is not working too.